# Referencing foreign keys across different users

Tags: oracle, reference, foreign-keys

I'm referencing a key that is part of another user:

Example:

```
create table emp 
     ( name char(10)
     , empid char(10)
     , dob date
     , phone char(14)
     , primary key(empid)
     , foreign key phone 
          references (user2.contacts)
       );
```

where `user2` holds a table which has phone as the primary key.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are all your columns really `char`? Why not `varchar2`? I would also recommend [looking at the syntax](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php) as you're not referencing a column in user2.contacts.

Answer (score 4):

USER2 needs to grant your user the REFERENCES privilege on their table.

```
grant references on contacts to user1
/
```

Note that, unlike other privileges, REFERENCES must always be granted directly.  USER1 will not be able to create a foreign key if the privilege is granted through a role.

The syntax for foreign keys requires us to include the primary key (or at least a unique key) column in the reference:

```
create table emp       
( name char(10)      
      , empid char(10)     
      , dob date
      , phone char(14)
      , constraint emp_pk primary key(empid)
      , constraint emp_contact foreign key (phone)
            references (user2.contacts.phone)        );
```

It is good practice to explicity name our constraints, as the system-generated names are a pain to work with.

Comment: i actually got it: it should be like this:

Answer (score -1):

it should be like this:

```
create table emp 
     ( name char(10)
     , empid char(10)
     , dob date
     , phone char(14)
     , primary key(empid)
     , foreign key phone 
          references user2.contacts)
       );
```

Comment: This is the same syntax as you posted inyour question, which is incorrect.  I have included a compilable statement in my answer.